# Xcode 12.4 How to remap key bindings

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm trying to change some key bindings in Xcode, but I can't figure out how to do it.

Following the steps in "Xcode Help" doesn't work. I'm assuming these docs are outdated?

[image]

For example, the binding I'm trying to edit is I'm trying to make "End" jump to end of line. Following the instructions in the help, I double click the line(2), but then when I press the "End" key(3), it just jumps to the bottom of the list, as if the line isn't selected.

This should be a simple thing, right? How do I do this? I couldn't find any help online, or even youtube videos, which really surprised me.

Comment: It sounds like it is obeying the End key rather than using it as the key binding. But in any case if all you want to do is jump to the end of the line, you do not need to remap anything, as Control-E already does it and Command-Right-Arrow already does it.

Comment: @matt yeah I know I can already do what I need with ctrl + e and ctrl + a. I probably should have mentioned that in the question. My reasoning for wanting to change is that my muscle memory is so used to cmd + end and cmd + home that I keep accidentally jumping to the beginning and end of file. I could try to reprogram my muscle memory, but I figured it would better to just remap, so that I don't mess myself up for the other IDEs that I use.

Comment: But you pressed end, not command end.

Comment: Nothing works though, not "cmd + end", not "end", not "a" or "cmd ~" . It just does the action of whatever I press, as if the field doesn't have focus. It's like they got rid of the ability to remap keybindings. The docs are obviously wrong or outdated, so I was wondering if there was a new method.

Comment: BTW, I want it to be "end", not "cmd + end". Essentially, I want it to work the way it works in VSCode. One of the common actions I do is "home -> shift + end -> cmd + c" to copy an entire line. To do that in xcode, I would do "ctrl + a -> shift + ctrl + e -> cmd + c", but my brain is just not trained for that and I keep jumping to end of document by mistake.

Comment: I'm not sure you can turn bare "end" into a shortcut. But hey, if VSCode can do it, that's cool. You are not the first person to want VSCode mappings in Xcode!!!

Comment: Could we circle back for a second? What is the _real_ goal here? Select and copy (not cut) an entire line? I may be able to suggest a way to configure that...

Comment: correct! Although, cutting an entire line is something I also use in VSCode

Comment: Best bet is probably a macro; see https://diamantidis.github.io/2018/12/07/xcode-shortcuts-and-custom-key-bindings